# How to detect Bluetooth state change using a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

I am trying to make an app that shows a toast when the device's Bluetooth turned on. I wanna do that even when my app is not running. So I should use a broadcast receiver, add some permissions, an intent-filter to android manifest and make a java class but I don't know the details.

What should I do? Which permissions should I use?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

AS far as permissions go, to detect the state change of bluetooth you need to add this to your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

An example receiver would look like this, you add this code to where you want to handle the broadcast, for example an activity:

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                    if(intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) 
    == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF)
    // Bluetooth is disconnected, do handling here
}

}

        };
```

To use the receiver, you need to register it. Which you can do as follows. I register the receiver in my main activity.

```
registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
```

You could also decide to add all of it to your AndroidManifest.xml. This way you can make a special class for the receiver and handle it there. No need to register the receiver, just make the class and add the below code to the AndroidManifest

```
<receiver
        android:name=".packagename.NameOfBroadcastReceiverClass"
        android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I only know to make a class of broadcast receiver

Comment: Should this receiver work if I close the app? Because it does not work.

Answer (score 23):

You have to take following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

and you have to write this as your intent filter in receiver tag.

```
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, for apps targeting **api 26** or higher, manifest declared broadcast receivers don't work anymore (reference here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), with some exceptions.
`android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED` is not in that list.

For bluetooth, you can only listen for changes on:

`ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED`, `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED`, `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED`

Comment: you listed action connection state changed twice

Comment: so what is the workaround? Once i register with ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED , what should the intent return me in onReceive . Or is there another technique to perform the task

Comment: You still can register your broadcast receiver at activity or fragment level, remember to unregister the receiver once its job is done

Comment: Thanks. I had problems detecting a change from "Bluetooth on" to "Bluetooth off" due to these changes in API 26. Works like a charm when I register the receiver in MainApplikation.kt:       
registerBlootoothReceiver(){
    val  filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
    bluetoothReceiver = BluetoothReceiver()
    registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, filter)
}