# How to detect bluetooth state with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I got a problem. I have read this topic: 
[How to detect Bluetooth state change using a broadcast receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888023/how-to-detect-bluetooth-state-change-on-off-using-a-broadcast-receiver)
and I wrote my app in the same way but when I run it and turn the bluetooth off the app is going to crash. System version: 4.0.3. Here is the code:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.lokalizing;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                                                 BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (state) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Turning Bluetooth off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Turning Bluetooth on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Włączono program", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    /* ... */

    // Unregister broadcast listeners
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

public void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lokalizing"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.lokalizing.MainActivity"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Toast implementation you missed to call the method show();

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<receiver>` declaration from your manifest.

You've declared `MainActivity` as both an `<activity>` and as a `<receiver>`. That is a definite no-no.

As you are creating the `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically in code and registering it in `onCreate()`. you don't need to have anything in the manifest for that.