# I cannot unregister my receiver and I'm still getting broadcasts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, illegalargumentexception

In my activity I have this:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    blc = new BluetoothClient(this);
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        blc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    blc = null;
}
```

This is the class that has the receiver: (Just the important parts)

```
public class BluetoothClient implements Closeable {

    final BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    Context context;
    ...

    public BluetoothClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            }
        };
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
        ...
    }

    ...

    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver); // Causes IllegalArgumentException
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered` every time in BluetoothClient.close. How can I do this correctly.

**Edit:** added all the code (it is probably too much to look through at a glance)

full code (except main activity, forgot about that) is here: http://pastebin.com/aVit2L8M

main activity: http://pastebin.com/6Ww8sKwE

Comment: How getting `context` in `close()` method?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I didn't include that in the question, but it's there.

Comment: if possible please show whole class code using pastebin like site

Comment: Ok, I've added the pastebin but I think all the relevant parts are here in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Either you are using a different context to unregister the broadcast rather than the context you registered with OR you are unregistering a different receiver.

Comment: The context is the application context, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the incoming context as a field in the constructor and use it when unregistering.

```
public class BluetoothClient {

    Context mContext;

    public BluetoothClient(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        ...
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
           mContext.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's there, I just didn't include it here.

Answer (score 0):

Register and Unregister the Broadcast Receiver in the onResume and onPause respectively and Use`LocalBroadCastManger.getInstance(mContext).register(YourReceiver)` and `LocalBroadCastManger.getInstance(mContext).unregister(YourReceiver)`
[Check on Official Documentation also](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Comment: I'm using broadcast receiver for bluetooth STATE_ON events. In this case I need the global BroadcastManager if I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes, for bluetooth, you should be using System level BroadcastManager. LocalBroadcastManager is for efficiency purpose if you are listening to your own generated and local broadcasts.

Comment: My mistake you have to register receiver in the manifest for Bluetooth please check that link. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888023/how-to-detect-bluetooth-state-change-on-off-using-a-broadcast-receiver)