# Android java Bluetooth Detect State Oncreate

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

i have this code to check if bluetooth state is on or off:

```
        if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch (state) {
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    bluetooth.setText("Bluetooth Disabled");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    bluetooth.setText("");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

How can i put this on the OnCreate so that when i start the app immediately without bt, the text "bluetooth is disabled" is shown. Because atm, it only triggers if I turn it on and turn it off again only.

Comment: try this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888023/how-to-detect-bluetooth-state-change-using-a-broadcast-receiver>

Comment: hmm i tried but didnt work but thx anyway

Comment: Either You want to check bluetooth on or off, or you want to check on bluetooth state change.

Comment: All i want is to detect the state as soon as the app starts and display "bluetooth disabled"

Comment: You just check `mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()` return true when bluetooth enable.