# BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() returns false just after reboot

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I've got a Service that on its onCreate method checks if BT is enabled, if not, it displays a notification. If the Service is started once the phone has been on for a while, everything works. However, if I reboot the phone and the Service is started using the intent: `boot.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);`, the notification is displayed. I guess BT is not ready yet?

```
public void onCreate(){
if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            notifyMissingBluetooth(getApplicationContext());
        }
}
```

How can avoid displaying this notification just after a reboot?

Comment: You can try to set a timeout for after 10 seconds for example. Or you can detect bluetooth state change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888023/how-to-detect-bluetooth-state-change-using-a-broadcast-receiver

Comment: the detection of BT state works! Thanks