# How can I make a service that activates over bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have made myself familiar with how services work and how Bluetooth works. My code already works if I am in the app, but I want it to also work when it is not open.

So I basically want to make a service. When I am running the app I simply open a Bluetoothsocket and wait until the other device sends that it's ready.

Here are my questions:

1. Would opening a Bluetoothsocket with a device in the service as long as it's nearby be a big battery issue?
2. Is there any downside to leaving the socket up?
3. Would listening to an Inputstream the whole day drain a lot of battery? I assume so, and if yes is there a better way to activate the service?

Comment: Register a broadcast like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888208/5502638
and run your service when bluetooth ON

Comment: I could make a broadcastreceiver that would run the onReceive function only if something is actually sent and all the time when a device is connected, right?

Comment: It will run the Method defined by you which i assume will run bacground service for executing your background task whenever you want like BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON or BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF

Comment: Ok thanks. My problem is that I don't want to run it the whole time Bluetooth is On but only when it is actually receiving an Inputstream. I could of course make the service check that the whole time, but that sounds like it's horrible for battery life.

Comment: From Where It will receive inputStream then!!